# How to inject ObjectMapper in spring

Tags: java, dependency-injection, spring-batch

I have a batch job written using Spring Batch

I have a config file below:

```
@Configuration
public class ObjectMapperConfig {

        @Bean
        public ObjectMapper objectMapper(){
            return new ObjectMapper();
        }
    }
```

I have Json Line aggregator as below:

```
public class JsonLineAggregator<T> implements LineAggregator<T> {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public String aggregate(final T item) {
        String result = null;
        try {
            result = mapper.writeValueAsString(item);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

I want to inject objectMapper and don't want to create it inside the JsonLineAggregator class. Any idea how can I implement it using DI ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@Autowired` annotation to inject the dependency in spring like this:

```
@Autowired
private final ObjectMapper mapper;
```

And Spring will inject the ObjectMapper bean created by you in `ObjectMapperConfig` class

Comment: so in JsonLineAggregator instead of  
private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
it should be 
@Autowired
private final ObjectMapper mapper; ?

Comment: yes @CyberPunk.... let me know if it doesn't helps

Comment: hmm it gives me the following error : 

java: variable mapper not initialized in the default constructor

Comment: I get java.lang.NullPointerException, it seems mapper is null

Comment: that means your config class which is returning the object mapper is not getting scanned, try to use @EnableAutoConfiguration annotation on Spring Application class